# "PHP Fatal error: Class 'AppController' not found" running CakePHP 2.0.5 on Windows IIS7

Tags: php, cakephp, iis, iis-7

I have a CakePHP (version 2.0.5) app that runs perfectly in my MAMP development environment. When I deploy it to a Windows IIS7 server I get the following error for any page I try to load:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'AppController' not found in
[my path]\app\Controller\PagesController.php on line 8
```

If I install a totally clean/new version of CakePHP version 2.0.5 to that IIS server, it runs without error. The IIS log file shows me nothing useful. Here's what the first few lines of PagesController.php looks like:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Pages Controller
 *
 * @property Page $Page
 */
class PagesController extends AppController {


    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('index','view','home');
    }
    ...
```

I'm at a loss as to what else I can check. Any ideas?
And to pre-empt the inevitable "don't use Windows server" replies - if it were up to me, I wouldn't.

Comment: I don't know CakePHP, but it may be linked to you include_path. If you don't know what to do about it, read the code of the function App::uses()

Comment: Just create AppController in /app folder extending Controller class.

Answer (score 0):

usually that is a 2.1 problem but take a look at:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-1-migration-guide.html

=> your controller has to be in your APP now (it is not part of the core anymore)- so just create one.